# Text beside a dynamic tickbox in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that populates checkboxes dynamically in the headerTemplate of a gridview. The header is a checkbox and a dynamic text/label.  However i can't get the headertemplate to display the text:

PageLoad:

```
   foreach (Module m in listModule)
        {
            TemplateField tfield = new TemplateField();
            CheckBox cbAll = new CheckBox();
            tfield.HeaderTemplate = new TickColumn();
            tfield.HeaderText = m.ModuleName; //<- This is not getting displayed.
            gvUsers.Columns.Add(tfield);
        }

class TickColumn : ITemplate
    {
        public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
        {
            CheckBox cbAll = new CheckBox();
            cbAll.ID = "cbAll";
            container.Controls.Add(cbAll);
        }
    }
```

For some reason, the HeaderText is not getting displayed.

Alternatively 
I have tried adding a label inside in the class but there i have no idea as of how to pass the value in:

```
static string lblname;
```

PageLoad:

```
foreach (Module m in listModule)
        {
            TemplateField tfield = new TemplateField();
            CheckBox cbAll = new CheckBox();
            tfield.HeaderTemplate = new TickColumn();
            lblname = m.ModuleName;
            gvUsers.Columns.Add(tfield);
        }


class TickColumn : ITemplate
    {
        public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
        {
            CheckBox cbAll = new CheckBox();
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Text = lblName;
            cbAll.ID = "cbAll";
            container.Controls.Add(cbAll);
            container.Controls.Add(lbl);
        }
    }
```

With this code, every dynamic column label's text becomes the same, the last element name get display throughout all the labels. How can i work my way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I realised i could actually pass the value using the constructor :

```
class TickColumn : ITemplate
    {
private String _label;
        public TickColumn(String p_label)
        {
            this._label = p_label;
        }
        public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
        {
            CheckBox cbAll = new CheckBox();
            cbAll.ID = "cbAll";
            cbAll.Text = this._label;
            container.Controls.Add(cbAll);
        }
   }
```